# Is it possible to copy only not protected attributes from one model to another in ROR3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to copy attributes from one model to another. So I'm explicitly setting them like this:

```
 user = current_user.attributes.slice("id", "name", "surname")
 user["user_id"] = user.delete("id")
 order.assign_attributes(user)
```

While I would like to do the following:

```
 order.attributes = user.attributes
```

But user object has a lot of other attributes which are protected from mass-assigment.
So is it possible to somehow assign only accessible attributes?

Comment: I think unless you have a very good reason to do so, you should associate User with Order and not copy the data.

Comment: I send data from my Order model to an external service and if any of related models (i.e User) are updated, it wouldn't be possible to get the original data. Which should not be the case.

Comment: Amazon allows you to have multiple addresses/identities and I guess they associate an address with order (and if you want to change the address it's considered a new address). But it's just me not liking the idea of copying information between models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't test it out but I think it should work

```
attrs = Order.accessible_attributes.each_with_object({}) do |name, attrs|
  attrs[name] = user.read_attribute(name) if name.present?
end

attrs[:user_id] = attr.delete(:id)
```

Comment: This is great piece of code and it almost works. the only thing that accessible_attributes has an empty object as a default value: ""=>nil
Anyway, it's not a big problem to get rid of it

Comment: Yeah, I changed it a little. Thank's for coop!